# How to catch a download with playwright?

Tags: node.js, playwright

I'm trying to download a file from a website using [Playwright](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright). The button that triggers the download does some js and then the download starts.

Clicking the button using the `.click` function triggers a download but it shows an error: *Failed - Download error*.

[image]

I've tried using the  devtools protocol [`Page.setDownloadBehavior`](https://vanilla.aslushnikov.com/?Page.setDownloadBehavior), but this doesn't seem to do anything.

```js
    const playwright = require("playwright");
    const { /*chromium,*/ devices } = require("playwright");
    const iPhone = devices["iPad (gen 7) landscape"];

    (async () => {
        const my_chromium = playwright["chromium"];
        const browser = await my_chromium.launch({ headless: false });
        const context = await browser.newContext({
            viewport: iPhone.viewport,
            userAgent: iPhone.userAgent
        });
        const page = await context.newPage();
        const client = await browser.pageTarget(page).createCDPSession();
        console.log(client);
        await client.send("Page.setDownloadBehavior", {
            behavior: "allow",
            downloadPath: "C:/in"
        });
        //...and so on
        await page.click("#download-button");
        browser.close();
    })();
```

[Full file here](https://github.com/bvn-architecture/cab_venn/blob/master/scraper.ts)

There is a [proposal for a better download](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/853) api in [Playwright](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright), but I can't find the current API.
There was a suggestion that [something to do with the `downloadWillBegin` event](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#event-downloadWillBegin) would be useful, but I've no idea how to access that from Playwright.

I'm open to the suggestion that I should use Puppeteer instead, but I moved to playwright because I couldn't work out how to download a file with Pupeteer either, and [the issue related to it suggested that the whole team had moved to Playwright](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/299).

Comment: In regards to the `downloadWillBegin` event, you may be able to use node's `EventEmitter`, which the [`Page`](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-page) class extends, e.g. `page.on('downloadWillBegin', doSomething);`

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [page.on("download")](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-event-download)

```
const browser = await playwright.chromium.launch({});
const context = await browser.newContext({ acceptDownloads: true });
const page = await context.newPage();
await page.goto("https://somedownloadpage.weburl");
await page.type("#password", password);
await page.click("text=Continue");
const download = await page.waitForEvent("download");
console.log("file downloaded to", await download.path());
```

Answer (score 0):

Embarassingly, I was closing the browser before the download had started.

It turns out that the download error was caused by the `client` section. However that means that I have no control over where the file is saved.

The download works when `headless: false` but not when `headless: true`.

If anyone has a better answer, that'd be great!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `waitForTimeout`.

I tried with `{headless: true}` &  `await page.waitForTimeout(1000);`

it's working fine. you can check same [here](https://github.com/nmanikiran/playwright-demos/blob/master/download.js)

Answer (score -3):

To download file (also its buffer) i highly recomend this module: [Got node module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got). Its much easier, clean and light.

```
(async () => {
const response = await got('https://sindresorhus.com')
    .on('downloadProgress', progress => {
        // Report download progress
    })
    .on('uploadProgress', progress => {
        // Report upload progress
    });

    console.log(response);
})();
```